# which folder can I put Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded Emulator from [this](http:////dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-28_r03.zip).  because my internet disconnected and android studio has not resum  and i don't know which folder put this zip file

anyone can help me?
 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your SDK folder -> system-images -> android-28 (if not exists you can create it) -> google_apis -> x86_64 (here you can extract the content of the zip file).